# Timer resumes from the previously paused value

Tags: android, eclipse, timer

Iam doing a IQtest app.I have inserted a timer to calculate the time taken for answering the questions.Whenever the quiz activity starts the timer starts.There is a pause button to pause timer and resume the timer.The timer works properly when I do the above steps in the manner as said above.But the problem is if the timer is runing and if I resume the timer the timer starts from the previously paused value.
Here is the QuizActivity.java

```
package com.example.iqtest;
public class QuizActivity extends Activity {
List<Question> quesList;
int score,qid,temp;
Question currentQ;
TextView txtQuestion;
RadioButton rda, rdb, rdc,rdd,rde;
Button butNext,agecal;
private Button pause,resume;
private TextView timerValue;
private long startTime = 0L;
private Handler customHandler = new Handler();
long timeInMilliseconds = 0L;
long timeSwapBuff = 0L;
long updatedTime = 0L;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz);
    timerValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    customHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerThread, 0);
    resume = (Button) findViewById(R.id.resume);
     resume.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View view) {
     startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        customHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerThread, 0);
         }
     });
     pause = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pause);
     pause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View view) {
             timeSwapBuff += timeInMilliseconds;
             customHandler.removeCallbacks(updateTimerThread);
         }
     });

    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras(); 
    qid=b.getInt("start");
    temp=qid;
    agecal = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttoncalage);
    agecal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()        
    {
        public void onClick(View view) 
        {
            Intent i = new Intent(QuizActivity.this,AgeCalculation.class);
            startActivity(i); 
        }

}); 
    DbHelper db=new DbHelper(this);
    quesList=db.getAllQuestions();
    currentQ=quesList.get(qid);
    txtQuestion=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    rda=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio0);
    rdb=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio1);
    rdc=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio2);
    rdd=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio3);
    rde=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio4);
    butNext=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    setQuestionView();
    butNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {     
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            RadioGroup grp=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
            RadioButton answer=(RadioButton)findViewById(grp.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
            if(currentQ.getanswer().equals(answer.getText()))
            {
                score++;
            }
            if(qid<(temp+20)){                  
                currentQ=quesList.get(qid);
                setQuestionView();
            }else{
                Intent intent = new Intent(QuizActivity.this, ResultActivity.class);
                Bundle b = new Bundle();
                b.putInt("score", score); //Your score
                intent.putExtras(b); //Put your score to your next Intent
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        }
    });
}
private void setQuestionView()
{
    txtQuestion.setText(currentQ.getquestion());
    rda.setText(currentQ.getopta());
    rdb.setText(currentQ.getoptb());
    rdc.setText(currentQ.getoptc());
    rdd.setText(currentQ.getoptd());
    rde.setText(currentQ.getopte());
    qid++;
}
private Runnable updateTimerThread = new Runnable() {
public void run() {
timeInMilliseconds = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - startTime;
updatedTime = timeSwapBuff + timeInMilliseconds;
int secs = (int) (updatedTime / 1000);
int mins = secs / 60;
secs = secs % 60;
int milliseconds = (int) (updatedTime % 1000);
timerValue.setText("" + mins + ":" + String.format("%02d", secs) + ":"+ String.format("%03d", milliseconds));customHandler.postDelayed(this, 0);
}
};

}
```

Comment: Can you clarify the issue. Is the issue with onResume (ie, when leaving and returning to the activity)? Or are you saying when you press Resume for the second time, it will start again from the first time it was paused? Or something else?

Comment: The issue is when...consider that the timer is running and the if i press resume button it starts from the value previously i paused at.for example if i paused it at 3 sec and i resume it and at 7 sec if i again click resume button(i.e clicking resume button twice continuously) the timer starts from 3 sec i.I doesn,t continue from 7 to 8 sec.

Comment: Why don't you disable the resume button until the user has clicked the pause button again? The most elegant solution would likely be to only show one of those buttons at a time.

Comment: thats what how to disable resume button until we click resume button?Iam a new bee and also tell me how could I put both resume and pause in same button?

Comment: Ok bro..I was waiting from long time...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most elegant solution is to hide the button that the user should not be allowed to press. In resume's onClickListener, add the following lines:

```
resume.setVisibility(View.GONE); // or View.INVISIBLE depending on what you want to do
pause.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

In pause's onClickListener, add the following lines:

```
resume.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
pause.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Also, in your layout, you should set one of these to `visibility="gone"` by default. Probably, resume.

If you instead want to keep both buttons visible at all times, then you will need to keep track of the current state with a boolean value: `resumeLastClicked`. Then, in each `onClickListener`, check which was the last `button` clicked and return if you do not want to perform the click.

Comment: this is OK but what should I change in code if I need to use a single button for both pause and resume?

Comment: You have a couple options. First, you can arrange your layout in such a way, that when one button is hidden and the other is made visible, they take up exactly the same space. Another option is to change the appearance of the button with `button.setText("Pause");` or `button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pause_image);` if the button is an image.

Comment: forget visible and hiding, can't I switch between pause and resume state in same button?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by this. If you mean you want to make one button both a pause and resume button, then you will need to dynamically change the button to look like a pause or resume button. If you are asking if there is a "pause" state for buttons, the best I can think of is to call `button.setEnabled(false);` to get it into a "paused" state and then set it to true to "resume" it.